# Step by step: Installing Python 3.3, Lighttpd & Pymongo on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04, pymongo, lighttpd

I'm currently migrating to new computer and I need to reinstall the software I am using which are:

- Python 3.3,
- Lighttpd (newest version),
- Pymongo (newest version),
- Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop (The System I'm using)

I started to install Python 3.3 by downloading it from the its official website (in tar.bz2 file) and by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3) tutorial. Afterwards I installed Lighttpd and changed the `lighttpd.conf` for Python by following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Lighttpd) tutorial, too.

I tried several paths for my `cgi.assign`, none of them worked. Especially `/opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3` should be working, but it shows `500 - internal Server error` all the time with a "hello world" test script.

Now regardless to this problem I have no clue on installing Pymongo. If I try to intall `pip OR easy_install python3.3` I have to manually download it and execute the `setup.py` with my `python3.3` executable, right? Because this always fails with an error:

```
`Error missing zlib on a bundle called distribute-0.7.3 (is this even the right tool I need, because it seems to be a legacy wrapper !?) or unknown url type: https for pymongo2.6.2 itself.`
```

I'm getting crazy with this setup. Why is this so difficult to handle? Other programs are just a few clicks to install even on a system like Ubuntu, but these particular development tools seem to be really difficult to install.If anybody has an idea on how to install all three together or has information on a better solution please help me out.

The system is used to program Python scripts in Eclipse and trying them out directly on the system (lighttpd). The database used is MongoDB. Python and MongoDB are communicating over the Pymongo driver. I am planning to use the system on a Server distribution on release and it has to be nicely scalable on a high amount of excecutions.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest to use the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip lightppd python-pymongo
```

Or if that only installs the python2.x pymongo, use pip, which you've just installed:

```
sudo pip-3.3 install pymongo
```

Or better yet, use a virtualenv with the help of `virtualenvwrapper` ([docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/))

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
... # follow instructions for installing virtualenvwrapper
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 -i pymongo mongoppd
workon mongoppd
```

... which will segregate the environment I've called 'mongoppd' from the rest of your system so you can't cause any trouble. Then you don't need `sudo` to `pip-3.3 install` things, just `workon mongoppd` then `pip-3.3 install [...]`. Or after the `-i` flag when you create the virtualenv to get it installed straight away.

In general, on Ubuntu, you should hardly ever have to install something manually. Your first attempt should be using `sudo apt-get install` (use tab-complete to see what's available or just google "ubuntu 12.04 packages [...]" and you'll find the list of packages). Then for python use `pip install` or `pip-3.3 install` as appropriate. You'll only need to run `python setup.py install` if you need to install a development version of a package or something obscure that's not on `pip`. I don't think there's a good reason to ever use `easy_install` these days.

Comment: this seems to be an easy way to do it. I didn't know that you can install pip for python 3 that easy! Just one thing: it needs to be "python3 pip install pymongo" otherwise you will use the python2.x's pip to install pymongo, or am I wrong?

Comment: Edited my answer... you were right about my mistake, but not the correct solution.

Comment: Don't forget to choose an answer as correct. However, I will note that if your problem is configuring lightppd and pymongo, my answer doesn't help with that (and neither can I).